# Angular2 RC5 NgClass Error

Tags: angular

I updated my app to angular RC5 version, when I try to run I'm getting the error as attached in the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't add `NgClass` to declarations in `AppModule`.

```
imports: [BrowserModule]
```

is enough.

Comment: I don't have `NgClass` in declarations in my `AppModule`. But still I'm getting this. Can you suggest why?

Comment: You have probably a bug in your code ;-) Hard to tell without seeing the code though.

Comment: What bug can it be? Do you have any guesses?

Comment: Please post your `@NgModule()` from `AppModule`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue, the problem is that I was injecting `CORE_DIRECTIVES` in `@NgModule()` in my `AppModule`.

Thank you [Gunter Zochbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer)